# How do I access the return of an axios function? Or should I be using callback?

Tags: asynchronous, axios

Getting some records and making a POST command to send off, am able to see the correct record Id's in the log so the logic works. Just don't know how to retrieve the values, I have tried async/await and get an unresolved promise response and running as is comes back undefined. New to async, any help is greatly appreciated!

```js
const axios = require('axios');
  exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    async function getJobId() { 
      var jobId
      axios({
          method: 'get',
          headers: {'<Api-Key>': '<my-api-key-value>'},
          url: 'https://api.my-website.com/v1/jobs',
          params: { jobNumber: event.jobNumber }
        })
        .then((res) => {
          var i,j,x;
          for (i in res.data) {
            for (j in res.data[i]){
              x = res.data[i][j];
              jobId = x.id;
            }
          }
          console.log('jobId:',jobId);
          return jobId;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log('getJobIdError');
          console.log(error);
        });
    }

    function getMaterialId() { 
        var materialId;
        axios({
          method: 'get',
          headers: {'<Api-Key>': '<my-api-key-value>'},
          url: 'https://api.my-website.com/v1/materials',
        })
        .then((res) => {
          var i,j,x;
          for (i in res.data) {
            for (j in res.data[i]){
              x = res.data[i][j];
              if(x.primaryVendor.vendorPart == event.material){
                materialId = x.id;
              }
            }
          }
          console.log('materialId:',materialId);
          return materialId;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log('getMaterialIdError');
          console.log(error);
        });
    }

    function getTechId() { 
        var techId;
        axios({
          method: 'get',
          headers: {'<Api-Key>': '<my-api-key-value>'},
          url: 'https://api.my-website.com/v1/technicians',
        })
        .then((res) => {
          var i,j,x;
          var fn = event.firstName;
          var ln = event.lastName;
          var fullName = fn.trim() + ' ' + ln.trim();
          for (i in res.data) {
            for (j in res.data[i]){
              x = res.data[i][j];
              if(x.name == fullName){
                techId = x.id;
              }
            }
          }
          console.log('techId:', techId);
          return techId;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log('getTechId');
          console.log(error);
        });
    }

    function allIds() {
      axios.all([
        getMaterialId(),
        getJobId(),
        getTechId()
      ]);
    }
    allIds();
 };
```

In the output log I get the correct record Id's:

Response:
null

Request ID: `"50972993-4971-4dcc-b577-0f253f3f3571"`
Function Logs:

> START RequestId: 50972993-4971-4dcc-b577-0f253f3f3571 Version: $LATEST
>   2019-08-17T21:51:51.192Z    50972993-4971-4dcc-b577-0f253f3f3571    techId: 1025
>   2019-08-17T21:51:51.233Z    50972993-4971-4dcc-b577-0f253f3f3571    materialId: 1725
>   2019-08-17T21:51:51.432Z    50972993-4971-4dcc-b577-0f253f3f3571    jobId: 37399080
>   END RequestId: 50972993-4971-4dcc-b577-0f253f3f3571
>   REPORT RequestId: 50972993-4971-4dcc-b577-0f253f3f3571  Duration: 1148.69 ms    Billed Duration: 1200 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 65 MB

Comment: You **cannot** return a value from a callback. Use a callback instead.

Comment: Then it only returns the first one of the three.

Answer (score 0):

I got it, Rohit Kashyap pointed me in the right direction, thank you Rohit. I was trying to avoid the nested axios as I read that can get sticky but seems to work pretty well here. It does what I need but am new to async so please let me know if anyone sees an issue.

```js
const axios = require('axios');
  exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

      var jobId;
      var materialId;
      var techId;

      axios.all([ 

        axios({
          method: 'get',
          headers: {'<Api-Key>': '<my-api-key>5'},
          url: 'https://api.my-website.com/v1/jobs',
          params: { jobNumber: event.jobNumber }
        })
        .then((res) => {
          var i,j,x;
          for (i in res.data) {
            for (j in res.data[i]){
              x = res.data[i][j];
              jobId = x.id;
            }
          }
          console.log('jobId:',jobId);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log('getJobIdError');
          console.log(error);
        }),

        axios({
          method: 'get',
          headers: {'<Api-Key>': '<my-api-key>5'},
          url: 'https://api.my-website.com/v1/materials',
        })
        .then((res) => {
          var i,j,x;
          for (i in res.data) {
            for (j in res.data[i]){
              x = res.data[i][j];
              if(x.primaryVendor.vendorPart == event.material){
                materialId = x.id;
              }
            }
          }
          console.log('materialId:',materialId);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log('getMaterialIdError');
          console.log(error);
        }),

        axios({
          method: 'get',
          headers: {'<Api-Key>': '<my-api-key>5'},
          url: 'https://api.my-website.com/v1/technicians',
        })
        .then((res) => {
          var i,j,x;
          var fn = event.firstName;
          var ln = event.lastName;
          var fullName = fn.trim() + ' ' + ln.trim();
          for (i in res.data) {
            for (j in res.data[i]){
              x = res.data[i][j];
              if(x.name == fullName){
                techId = x.id;
              }
            }
          }
          console.log('techId:', techId);
        })

        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log('getTechIdError');
          console.log(error);
        })
      ])
      .then((res) => {
        callback( null, {
            jobId,
            materialId,
            techId,
        });
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
          console.log('getAllIdError');
          console.log(error);
      });
  };
```